# R image2d: Changing x, y, z axes labels

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I found this awesome tutorial on changing the x and y axes labels in ggplot and used it successfully on bar charts and scatterplots:

http://www.moeding.net/archives/32-Metric-prefixes-for-ggplot2-scales.html#comments

I would like to extend this capability to this 'heat map' that I have developed as well.  Here is the code:

```
library(plot3D)

format_si <- function(x,...) {
  # Format a vector of numeric values according
  # to the Semi-International System of Units.
  #
  # Based on code by Ben Tupper
  # https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-January/299804.html
  # Args:
  #   ...: Args passed to format()


  function(x) {
    limits <- c(1e-24, 1e-21, 1e-18, 1e-15, 1e-12,
                1e-9,  1e-6,  1e-3,  1e0,   1e3,
                1e6,   1e9,   1e12,  1e15,  1e18,
                1e21,  1e24)
    prefix <- c("y",   "z",   "a",   "f",   "p",
                "n",   "µ",   "m",   "",   "k",
                "M",   "B",   "T",   "P",   "E",
                "Z",   "Y")

    # Vector with array indices according to position in intervals
    i <- findInterval(abs(x), limits)

    # Set prefix to "" for very small values < 1e-24
    i <- ifelse(i==0, which(limits == 1e0), i)

    return(paste(format(round(x/limits[i], 1),
                 trim=TRUE, scientific=FALSE, ...),
          prefix[i], sep=""))
  }
}



#Generate some data
xs<-rnorm(50000)*100000
ys<-rnorm(50000)*100000
zs<-sin(xs)*10000000
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(xs,ys,zs))

#Heat Map
df$x<-cut(df$xs, breaks=50, labels=FALSE)
df$y<-cut(df$ys, breaks=50, labels=FALSE)
df.max<-expand.grid(x=1:50, y=1:50)
df.max<-merge(df.max, aggregate(zs~x+y, df, max), all.x=TRUE)
z<-t(matrix(df.max$zs, nr=50, nc=50))
x.values <- min(df$xs)+(0:49)*diff(range(df$xs))/50
y.values <- min(df$ys)+(0:49)*diff(range(df$ys))/50
image2D(x=x.values, y=y.values, z, rasterImage = TRUE, contour = list(lwd = 2, col = jet.col(11)),
    main="Random Data", xlab="random xs",ylab="random ys", clab="zs=sin(xs)", ylim=c(0,max(df$ys)*1.05), 
    xlim=c(0,max(df$xs)*1.05))
```

In ggplot, I would just add `scale_y_continuous(labels=format_si())` to my plot and it the axis labels would be 1M instead of 1.0e6 or 1000000.  I have tried turning the labels off inside of image2d and then using `axes(1, format_si())` but that doesn't work either.  Has anybody tried this before?

Comment: No, and I think you are better off scaling to smaller values and putting the units in the legends (that is what the examples for `plot3D` do.. For example I noticed that when I changed the scale on these by a factor of 1 million smaller (divided by 1e6), the coloring changed quite drastically. Makes me think that there is a bug somewhere, and it is more likely to be correct for smaller values of z.

Comment: Also this example only needs `plot3D`. I would delete the references to the other libraries as they caused me to install them before I noticed, and the more libraries installed, the more cluttered a system becomes.

Comment: Sorry, this code is a snippet from a much larger model where I need those libraries.

Comment: Yes, I realize that, but you should delete them out of your SO questions. They just distract, and mislead people into installing them unnecessarily (like me :).